# Not able to create SQL Server database through AWS Toolkit in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, amazon-web-services

I am following the AWS user manual and trying to deploy a .NET application to AWS.

Here are the thing I have done:

- Sign up for AWS account
- Install AWS toolkit for MS VC 2010
- Created DB instance through AWS toolkit

So the next step would be to create a DB database in the AWS as in step 3 of

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

However, when I follow the instruction and right click on create SQL server instance, nothing happened.

Anyone can give some clues why this happening? Thank you very much..

Comment: was your DB created?

Comment: Yes, I have successfully created a DB instance, but when I want to create a SQL server database under this instance following the instruction, it is not corresponding.